# Proguard in Android

Tags: android, proguard

I am using proGuard to obfuscate my application. I included library jars in my application and I am using ant to build the application. But in the building phase  I am getting the following exception.

```
-dex:
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/fiberlink/Desktop/Work/MaaS360/Maas360ControlAgent/bin/classes.dex...
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:206)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)
       [dx] 1 error; aborting
```

I am not getting what the problem is... Somebody Please help...

Answer (score 0):

What does your `proguard.cfg` file look like? You'll also want `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` in your `default.properties` file (changed later on API level).

Mine is below, and works fine.

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: My proguard.cfg is same as yours except that I am using some library jars. If I havent enabled the proguard then I wont get any errors like these

Comment: Exclude your lib from proguard

Comment: If I am not using the proguard option it will work fine.If I use that option, optimization will work fine but in dex phase I will get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be sure not to forget anything special regarding Android when using Proguard is to take as a base file the one from the SDK, located here :

```
C:\SDK\Android\sdk\tools\proguard\examples\android.pro
```

This file is well documented and preset every parameters that need to be set for an Android application.